# How to do joins with multiple tables to calculate a value?

Tags: sql-server, join

I'm new to SQL and trying to figure out the most efficient way to use case/when and join statements. Let me know how I should approach this. Please see the tables and logic below:

[image]

- Find out whether the store associated with each transaction is H, M, or L
- After finding out the H, M, or L classification from table B, then join with table 3 to find associated adjusted value
- As an example, transaction 1 would be classified as an H and based and criteria B is an X, so the associated adjusted value would be 0.01

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. (Constraints, indexes & plans are critical.) [ask] [help]

Answer (score 1):

> Find out whether the store associated with each transaction is H, M, or L

you can use join Table_B on store column to get Creteria_A

```sql
    select A.*,B.Creteria_A
    from Table_A  A
    left join Table_B B on A.store = B.store
```

> After finding out the H, M, or L classification from table B, then join with table 3 to find associated adjusted value
>   As an example, transaction 1 would be classified as an H and based and criteria B is an X, so the associated adjusted value would be 0.01

you can use sql-server `cte update` to do it

```sql
with cte as (
    select A.*,B.Creteria_A,C.Adjusted_Value
    from Table_A  A
    join Table_B B on A.store = B.store
    join Table_C C on B.record = C.record
)
update cte set [value + Adjusted Value] = Value + Adjusted_Value;
```

> thanks Wei! Is there a way to do this without CTE?

you can use `update join`

```sql
UPDATE
    Table_A  
SET
    [value + Adjusted Value] = Value + C.Adjusted_Value;
FROM 
    Table_A  A
    join Table_B B on A.store = B.store
    join Table_C C on B.record = C.record
;
```

Comment: @jackhenry21 you can use update join,i have updated answer.